# Invalid Key PB: no elements

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

For my android app I am writing endpoints code for backend.

In my appengine datastore method, when I try to access my Entity using key, I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Key PB: no elements

following are code snippets I have tried out

```
Key key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(keyId);

key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(URLEncoder.encode(keyId, "utf-8"));
```

keyId is of type String.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue myself!
Instead of using stringToKey I used createKey for the KIND I want.
Passed the key as String

```
 Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(<KIND>,keyId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
key = KeyFactory.stringToKey(""+keyId);
```

Comment: I will try, but how will this help as keyId is already a String?